# How to use print statement in python

Tags: python

How do I write hello world in python? I can't run my python program after typing hello world.

```
Print(hello world)
```

Isn't it the right way. I don't know I am new at this how do I do?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. It is great to see you start the journey of learning python. While Stack Overflow is a great place to ask questions, I would recommend you to search for answers within Stack Overflow or other websites. For example, you could learn about `print` statement using this link https://www.w3schools.com/python/ or https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all change the question name to something related to the question.

Your answer:

change `Print(hello world)` to `print("Hello World")` and this might solve the problem.

You used capital `P` and typed `hello world` without quotation marks `""`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `Print(Hello World)` to `print("Hello World")` or you'll get a syntax error. You should also have a Python interpreter. I suggest you should download Python 3.8 from [Python.org](https://python.org). Then you'll need to run IDLE or an editor and then you should write your code. You can run it with `F5` or with the `Run` button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use „“. This way, python knows, that you want to print a string. If you don’t use „“ python wants to print a variable called hello world but the variable doesn’t exist.
Also, you should write print with a small p.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `print("hello world")` as this is the correct syntax. You have to add "" for strings also you have to use small p instead of capital P.